# "I wish" は日本語でどう言いますか。

Tags: translation

"I wish I could be there" , "I wish I were there" , "I wish I could do that", etc. in Japanese is "______れば/けべ/ければ/いべ_____たいと思っています" ？ Does it follow this pattern? And is there any other ways to relay the feeling of "I wish_____" in Japanese?

Comment: Not a good answer, but I have also seen the following: `______ならばよかった（なー）` as in, `it would be great if___`, which has a similar feel

Comment: `れば/けべ/ければ/いべ_____たい` -- 「けべ」「いべ」って何ですか？

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to express this, with the _____なら/なければいいのに form being frequently used colloquially. 行かなければよかったのに... もっと背が高かったらいいのに.. etc. This form shows regret for not doing/being something.

This question has been asked before. See [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/35712/expressing-a-regretful-wish), [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/53640/how-do-you-say-if-only-things-were-different), or [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/18107/i-wish-i-hadnt-gone-there) for previous answers.